# Kernel of homomorphism between two cyclic groups of diferent order

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

In Malik's abstract algebra one can find the following exercise (and I paraphrase):

> Let $f$ be a homomorphism from a cyclic group of order 8 onto a cyclic group of order 4. Determine $\ker f$.

Consider $f: \langle a \rangle_8 \to \langle b \rangle_4$

So: I need to find all the elements $x\in \langle a \rangle_8$ such that $f(x) = e$ ($e \in \langle b \rangle_4$, of course). I can write $x$ as a power of $a$: $x = a^k, k\in \mathbb{Z}$. And then: $$e = f(x) = f(a^k) = \underbrace{f(a)f(a)f(a)\dots f(a)}_{k \mbox{ times, because } f\mbox{ is an homomorphism}} = f(a)^k$$

Now, $f(a) \in \langle b \rangle_4$, $f(a)$ can be then expressed as a power of $b$: $f(a) = b^q$. $$e = f(a)^k = (b^q)^k = b^{qk}$$ Now, I can imply that $4\mid qk$. And this is where my question comes in: because I can assume without loss of generality that $0< q\leq 3$, **can I say that $4\mid k$?** Because, if I can, I could determine the kernel in the following way: $$\ker f = \{x \in \langle a \rangle_8 \mid x = a^k, 4\mid k\}$$

Comment: No. $q$ could equal $2$, and then only $2$ must divide $k$. But it looks like you are on the right track otherwise.

Comment: I see, nice counterexample. I'll keep looking for it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the map is surjective the order of the kernel is $\frac84=2$. what subgroup of $<a>$ does this identify?

Comment: How can I arrive to the conclusion that the order of the kernel is 2?, does it have something to do with homomorphism theorems?

Comment: No worries: I can see it now. Thanks to Lagrange's Theorem, the order of the quotient group (that is, the amount of cosets) is the actual quotient between the orders of the group and the normal subgroup. And because we're talking about an isomorphism, both orders should be equal.

Answer (score 2):

As given $f$ is onto therefore by First isomorphism theorem $ord(kerf)$=$2$ Now as every group of order 2 is generated by a single element of order 2 therefore identifying $kernal$ is same as finding elements of order 2 and as $Z/8$ is cyclic therefore have only one element of order $2$.So $ker(f)=<4>$